# How to Permanently setup Class path of Nodejs in Linux Mint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, linux-mint

I just Tried to Install Nodejs Version 6.9.4 in Linux Mint.
I just followed these simple steps:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v6.3.1/node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz node-v6.3.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ mkdir -p /usr/local/nodejs
$ mv node-v6.3.1-linux-x64/* /usr/local/nodejs
```

(refer to: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_environment_setup.htm)
and After performing these steps successfully, I setup the class Path as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin
```

I ran a sample node js program of hello world and it ran successfully. But however when I exited my current terminal and opened a new one, When I typed the following command:

```
node -v
```

and I Received the output:

```
The program 'node' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt install nodejs-legacy
```

so everytime I have to export the classpath in order to be able to use my node js. I tried the following command as a superuser to manually add the class path:

```
~/.bashrc
```

and I got the following output:

```
bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

is there any Possible Solution so that I could permanently set up the class path without installing nodejs-legacy?

Thank you Very Much..!

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/install-nodejs-ubuntu-debian-linux-mint-using-ppa.html) ?

Comment: Dear Tareq, I Just want to permanently setup the class path for node js as I have applied different steps for installing it..!

Comment: this way will move node.js to one of already defined PATHs like /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin so it will make it easier for you!

Comment: okay..! thank you very much..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin` to your ~/.bashrc file.

Instead of trying to execute the .bashrc file (`~/.bashrc`), you need to source it.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

However, you shouldn't need to run this command every time you open the terminal. The .bashrc file should be automatically sourced every time you open your terminal.

I suggest you read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) for what bashrc does.

**Step-by-step instruction:**

Open your ".bashrc" file with your favorite editor. For example: nano

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Paste in `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/nodejs/bin` to the bottom of the file, then save and exit nano. (Press "ctrl-x" then "y" and "Enter").

Just restart your terminal.

If you don't want to restart your terminal, just use this command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Note:**
"~" means your home directory. The .bashrc file is basically a hidden file stored in your user home directory. The "." in front of bashrc makes it hidden.

Comment: That was very helpful but as I am a new bee in Linux , can you please provide step by step procedure along with commands to follow inorder to setup the class path.

Comment: @James I've updated the answer with step-by-step instruction. Tell me if you can get it working.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mr. Nelson. I got it working. It solved my problem. It was very simple, though I made it complicated. Thanks Again.. Have A Great Day..!